# Add and remove class redraw browser?

Tags: jquery, html, browser

Can someone shed some light on the following for me:

1)I have an html table that is created dynamically.  It has 30+ columns and over 100 rows. I have been able to use the arrow buttons to navigate in the cells of the tables.  When I move to the next cell, I set focus to the new cell and also change the border of the cell.

Should I use .addClass('className') and .removeClass('className') or should I use .css('border','1px solid') to change the border of the cell.

Are both similiar in terms of the browser redrawing itself?  Is one preferable over the other?

2)If instead, I click on another cell instead of using the arrows to move to the cell, I want to clear the previous cells border.  Because I don't have a reference to the old cell, I end up having to clear the whole 'table tr' border, which might be an overkill.

Basically, what is the best implementation of putting a border around a cell when I either click on it or arrow to it?  And the best way to remove it?  I am noticing a bit of a lag and I don't know if it's the browser redrawing the page due to the addClass and removeClass.

Thanks in advance

Comment: using a class is far more maintainable. My guess would be the performance hit is from the way you are selecting the rows, not the adding/removing of class or style.

Comment: You wouldn't need to remove the border from all cells.  You could target the cell that has the border... `$("td.className").removeClass("className");`

Answer (score 3):

> Are both similiar in terms of the browser redrawing itself?

A redraw is a redraw, not matter what caused it.

> Is one preferable over the other?

The first one – because it separates logic and presentation better.

Maybe next week you want a 2px border instead, or a dotted one, or add a background color – so you just change your CSS, and leave the script logic as it is.

> If instead, I click on another cell instead of using the arrows to move to the cell, I want to clear the previous cells border. Because I don't have a reference to the old cell, I end up having to clear the whole 'table tr' border, which might be an overkill.

Well then why don’t you keep a reference to the previously highlighted cell …?

Comment: You've said the 2nd one is better, but then explained why the 1st is better ;)